# Error when knitting pdf in Rmarkdown: tlmgr.pl: Remote database older than the local installation

Tags: tlmgr, rmarkdown

My Rmarkdown script stopped working all of a sudden (trying to knit a pdf), and it's giving me the following error.

> tlmgr.pl: Remote database (revision 69718 of the texlive-scripts package)
> seems to be older than the local installation (rev 69731 of
> texlive-scripts); please use a different mirror and/or wait a day or two.

I have tried reinstalling Tinitex, Miktex and Texlive, changing repository to other mirrors using TexLive and waited a day but the problem persists.
I found the tlmgr:pl file in C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive and the second line states

> $Id: tlmgr.pl 69653 2024-01-31 21:52:46Z karl $

So it is version 69653, not 69731 but maybe I have another file somewhere else?

I don't know what else to try, please help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Wait, wait, wait ...reinstalling Tinytex, Miktex and Texlive?  What a mess!!  I guess that you have the issue with Tinytex but you try to fix it with the wrong tlmgr. The first to discover is  what are you using really.  A good start could be a Quarto document with `latex-tinytex: false` or `latex-tinytex: true` to check if the error disappear with the first or the second option (or never). Uninstall everything and then install only one distro could be  also a good start (slower, but more clarifying).

Comment: Sorry, should have said that I uninstalled each one before trying the next one. As of this morning I had Texlive and Tinitex, set up to use tinitex and it worked this morning up until around 9am (UK time) where it failed again, with a similar error message (but with different version numbers, again the local being newer than the remote repository).

Comment: I have uninstalled everything and reinstalled Tinytex. It loaded some packages but it failed when trying to load sectsty.sty. Same error as above.

Comment: Ok, it's working now with Miktex, allowing for on-the-fly installation set to Always. Not sure that it was the direct solution to the issue above but it's working!